# QGIS - List of values in attribute form - Add a new value in editing mode

Tags: qgis

I'm working with `QGIS 3.16.5` (Hannover) and list of values in attribute form. I can easily create a list of predefined items with a combo box, no issues with this.

But I'm asking if is there an option/possibility to have an "Add" option to allow an user to add a new item in this list in editing mode ?

**Actual behaviour**

[image: actual_behaviour]

**Desired behaviour**

[image: desired_behaviour]

I don't find anything about this in the [docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#edit-widgets). This kind of option could be very usefull.

Comment: No, not yet at least. The nearest thing you can currently get is changing the widget type to "Value Relation" and enable the "Use Completer" option. Would be a neat feature request though ;)

Comment: Nice trick, I haven't think of this option. It could be a great improvement, especially with a QField usage when users are in the field and can't change the QGIS project parameters.